# MVVM view model design

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inversion-of-control, prism

I'm currently trying to wrap my ahead around the `MVVM-Pattern`. In addition I'm using `PRISM` for IoC-support etc. But there is one thing (among others) in particular, that I'm not comfortable with the way I'm doing it, because it seems a bit strange to me, so maybe I didn't get it right.

Let's say I want to make a `ListView` that displays part of a database schema. So on the "top-level" I would have one element per database. Within these elements I want to show the tables in that database and within that, the column names of that table.

The way I'm doing this now, is to create 3 view models (+1 Base-ViewModel for the view hosting the `ListView`). One for each "layer" of the `ListView`. So I'd have f.e. a `DatabaseViewViewModel`, a `DatabaseTableViewViewModel` and a `DatabaseTableColumnViewViewModel` (names are not too hot here).

So the Base-ViewModel has an `ObservableCollection` of `DatabaseViewViewModel`s, the `DatabaseViewViewModel` has an `ObservableCollection` of `DatabaseTableViewViewModel`s and so on.

So obviously those view models need some configuration data (the `DatabaseTableViewViewModel` f.e. needs to know it's database). In my opinion an object should be completly initialized after creation, so I'd like to pass that data in the constructor. Of course, that makes it impossible to resolve those view models from an IoC container. But I "have" to resolve it, since they have some dependencies that need to be resolved (f.e. an `IEventAggregator`).

As far as I've read, the (or at least one) way to handle this, is to use `Factories` to create the view models, but I'm not quite happy with that layout. It seems a bit "oversized".

So I wanted to ask you, if I have maybe overlooked something. 
Is my view model design valid? Or how would you design your view models for this kind of "hierarchical" `ListView`?

**Edit:** For clearification: The reason I'm creating those 3 different view models is, that I think it gets a little messy (in fact I'm having trouble to come up with an idea of how to implement that at all off the top of my head) when you try to expose properties of objects further down the hierarchy (f.e. the column names) for databinding.

Of course I could use dependency properties or implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` in my model classes - and that might in fact be a good way to go for a new project - but let's assume you have a model, that can't be easily modified.

**Edit2:** Regarding Sheridan's comment on the weird view model classes, that's because in the app I'm developing, the database schema IS my data. I'm not working on the actual data in the database. (I'm developing a MySQL Management Agent for Microsoft's Forefront Identy Manager. That management agent needs to know the schema of the database (relationships etc.), which currently gets read in from an XML file. So I'm building a UI to comfortable create said XML file. If I was working with the actual data in the database, the view models would most certainly look completely different.

Comment: Excuse my nit-picking, but I can't resist the thought that there's a lot of redundancy in the naming convention. A `ViewModel` is a model of a view. What's a `ViewViewModel` then? A view model of a view? Too much of this in here. :) Maybe this is what clutters your mind and hinders understanding of MVVM?

Comment: :) Yeah I agree, that's kinda stupid. The idea was, say I have a `DatabaseView` and a corresponding view model. So I called it `DatabaseView(_)ViewModel`

Comment: I see, but I think you'd agree it makes more sense to have: `Database` (the model), `Database(_)View` and `Database(_)ViewModel` as it at least reflects the roles of objects.

Comment: Definitly! In fact, when I think about it, to call it `...ViewViewModel` could imply a coupling between the view and the view model, which to avoid is kind of the whole point of mvvm... :)

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, for those dependencies that are known at compile time I use the IoC container to configure them and inject them in to the relevant classes.  For those dependencies that require runtime information (for example the selection of a database) I inject a statically configured factory that enables me to create those objects at runtime.

To this end I do not think that that the use of Factories is "oversized".

The important thing is to model your view models in the correct way, which you seem to be doing.  Databases contain tables - consequently your view models should (and does) reflect this.  I think you are going down the right path!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you *might* be slightly on the wrong path here... in my opinion, it is far easier to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface directly in your data objects, rather than having a separate view model for each of them. Your .NET classes won't necessarily match your database schema... think about Object Oriented Programming:

Your database might have `Company`, `Person` and `Address` tables, but in .NET, your `Company` class might contain a collection property of type `Person` and each `Person` class could have a property of type `Address`... so now we are building hierarchical data classes... just perfect to be displayed in hierarchical controls in the UI.

Now continuing this example into the view model level, you would just need to provide a collection of the `Company` data types to bind to an `ItemsSource` control property and maybe a single `Company` property to bind to a `SelectedItem` control property.

One thing that rang alarm bells for me while reading your question was regarding your `DatabaseViewModel`... basically no, no, no. We should *never* see a view model with this name (in a large scale application at least). The data comes via the model and *not* the view model... and we don't match our view models to our database tables... just use basic data type classes for that.

Think of it like this... my data type classes hold *all* properties for each of my database table columns, but are connected in a more 3D, or hierarchical manner. I generally have one .NET class for each table, but weak entity, or joining tables are usually implemented in .NET as one class *having* a property of the type of another class in them.

The model (database access) class fills these data type classes from calls to the database and pass them to the view model classes. My view model classes are simply collections of all of the properties required in each particular view and most of these have the data type classes as their type. My view models also have methods that provide the functionality for the views.

I personally feel that using MVVM goes hand in hand with WPF and wouldn't dream of using WPF without it (except for the smallest applications). I feel that you *might* benefit from some more reading about MVVM, although maybe the answers you receive here might be enough.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Implenting the `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the model would be the way to, when you have access to the model code. But what if you dont? As for the kind of weird view model classes, that's because in the app I'm developing, the database schema IS my data. I'm not working on the actual data in the database.

Comment: I think the point of having all those database concepts there could be a sign it's a database management type application, not that it works directly with the db - at least I hope that's the case :) Anyway, you say that the .Net classes can not match the DB but that can be the case with the VMs not matching the models as well. What you do in these cases is make ViewModels for each Model and map them using whatever strategy (Automapper or the likes if it helps). And about initialization... get creative. Use the event aggregator. Whatever works :P

Comment: Forgot to add: there are many other reasons for wrapping models in viewmodels; once I needed to show model objects in a tree and ended up wrapping the models because I needed expanded/selected related properties on the viewmodels and also lazy loading for child objects.

Comment: @AlexPaven, I totally accept that some developer prefer to work that way... I just choose not to in general.

Comment: @Sheridan And I totally understand and agree, but how else would you solve something like my second comment? :) And if you want to be pedantic, binding models directly to views is not really the preferred MVVM way; it's more flexible to handle any UI concerns in separate viewmodels, and you can do that more easily if you wrap your models; it makes for a more decoupled architecture. Of course I always try to get away without doing it, and many of WPF's features help with keeping UI concerns in the view only. But sometimes you must.

Comment: Also the OP did mention that we should assume that the models are not under our control - I had that too at one point and that's another perfectly valid reason to have viewmodel wrappers :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all I dont think you need three viewmodels. These shoud be "Models". DataBaseModel will be the parent model containing list of TableModel which in turn contains ColumnModel list.

Then you need just one ViewModel which will have List of DataBaseModel and this viewmodel will serve as Datacontext for your view. The viewmodel will have default constructor so it can be resolved. In order to initialize the DatabaseModel, use configuration to provide connection strings to intialize it.

For hierarchical structure use TreeView with HierarchicalDataTemplates to show the hierarchy.

Comment: the problem with just one view model is, that it gets kind of messy when you want to expose properties of the TableModel or ColumnModel for databinding. that is the reason why I'm using those mentioned 3 models. Any thoughts?

Comment: your can directly bind to the model properties. Make your models INotifyPropertyChanged and any change in them will be notified to the view.